# Hide a get php url

Tags: php, mysql, url, get

I have a dynamic table consisting of all user details and also a link on click it directs to another page where we can view specific course detail about a specific user..
My problem is that i wish to hide the ID and can't use the post method as well.. Is there any way to hide the url or any method to do this

```
echo "<td>"  . $lead['lastname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" .'<a href="course_complete_sup.php?id'.$row1['userid'].'" class="lien2" value='.$row1['userid'].'/>Course Completed</a>' ."</td>" ;
echo "<td>" .'<a href="course_progress_sup.php?id='.$row1['userid'].'" class="lien2" value='.$row1['userid'].'/>Course Progress</a>' ."</td>" ;
echo
```

Thx

Comment: Is the id based on the current logged in user?

Comment: Security through obscurity !== security. You should make your app secure, not hide necessary but probably easily guessable information.

Comment: no its based upon a hiarchy where only specific user info will appear

Comment: I don't see any problem? Why couldn't these IDs be exposed?

Comment: since any one can modify the id and have information.. for security issues...

Comment: you do not understand security issues. LISTEN to what thay says! is is INTENDED top be modified! You shoud check it in the server side.

Comment: well suppose u r in a company, u have the right to view certain info, wat if other people just make enter an id at random and view all info not intended to him... it will be wrong dr..

Comment: That's why you need to **make your app secure**! Require logins. Test whether a user is allowed to view something or not. Don't display the information to them if they're not. **Implement a security model.**

Comment: People will find a way to guess. There really are very smart and clever people out there who are looking to blow holes into your application. What you need to do is to modify the screen that shows the info. So if I shouldn't see this information, I won't be able to, _even if I tamper with the id in the URL_.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

ok i used the method of regality..

$_SESSION['rand_seed'] = rand(1,100000);

echo ""  . $lead['lastname'] . "";

```
echo "<td>" .'<a href="course_complete_sup.php?id='.md5($row1['userid']).$_SESSION['rand_seed'].'" class="lien2" value='.$row1['userid'].'/>Course Completed</a>' ."</td>" ;
```

then when it direct the page course_complete_sup.php

$ids = $_GET['id'];
    $salt = $_SESSION['rand_seed'];
    unset ($_SESSION['rand_seed']);

```
if ($salt < 1)
{
  header("location: access-denied.php");

}
```

else 
{

```
 list($var1) = explode($salt, $ids, 2);

}


$encrypt = mysql_query("select distinct(userid)  from course_complete ");
{
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($encrypt))
{

  $r= md5($row['userid']);
   if( $r== $var1){
                $id = $row['userid'];
   }
```

}

```
}
```

And it works!!!!!!!!!!

Thx regality and u all...

Cheersssssss

Answer (score 0):

Nope, if you use GET, the parameters are going to be visible in the URL. You can try redirecting right away, but that does not really help if security is the issue.

Is there a particular reason you can't use POST? That would really be the way to go if you need to hide that information.

Comment: i've got two pages 1 for complete and 1 for progress from 2 different links.. for security measures itself, i need to hide them...

Answer (score -3):

The only way to prevent the user from seeing the url is by doing everything on the server, which is typically overly complicated and slower. You should redesign your code so that it isn't a security issue for the url to be seen, but if you can't then you would have to send a hash or arbitrary number in the link.

For example, you could create the following link:

```
'<a href="newaction.php?action='.md5("user_id=" . $row1['userid'])).'" class="lien2" />Course Progress</a>'
```

and without knowing anything about your php code, I would suppose you could do something like the following in newaction.php:

```
<?php
// ... a bunch of code ...
if ($_GET['action'] == md5("user_id=" . $row1['userid'])) {
    course_progress_sup($row1['userid']);
}
// .. a bunch more code ...
?>
```

I remind you that this is a bad idea, and you should rethink how you are going about this, but you could do something like it if you had to.

Comment: to get this we should encrypt the id at the directed page using sql and match the the GET id.. this would take long time.. but its a gud idea... but it will remain static since any number can be encrypted in md5

Comment: if that is a concern then you would want to use a random seed in the hash. You can do:$_SESSION['rand_seed'] = rand(1,100000); and then put that into every md5: ....href="newaction.php?action='.md5("user_id=" . $row1['userid']) . $_SESSION['rand_seed']).'" clas.....

Comment: naaaaa.... i've tried it... but while matching the values from the get and from md5 convertion... it does'n work...

Comment: i've tried to do it and get the information.. but how can i remove the random seed in order to match the id with the database